# Untar Without Top-Level Directory

Tags: command-line, tar

I have a tar (websites.tgz) that contain a bunch of Drupal websites that are tarred up starting with 'htdocs'

I need to untar them into

```
/local/htdocs/web1
/local/htdocs/web2
```

and so on.  But I cannot place the websites.tgz file in /local and extract downward due to permissions.  It is currently in my home directory.  How can I untar the contents under /local/htdocs, without including the top-level htdocs directory?

I am trying to avoid having:

```
/local/htdocs/htdocs/web1
/local/htdocs/htdocs/web2.
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you don't have permissions to place the tarfile in `/local`, then you can't create the subdirectories. Or do they exist already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `-C` option in some tar implementations to specify the base path for extraction. The following will work for your example.

```
tar -xvz -C /local -f websites.tgz
```

Or if your `tar` doesn't have the `-z` or `-C` options:

```
gunzip < websites.tgz | (cd /local && tar xvf -)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the --strip-components=NUMBER option of GNU tar:

```
--strip-components=NUMBER
  strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction
```

Your command would be:

```
tar -xfz /path/to/websites.tgz --strip-components=1 -C /local/htdocs/
```